# Почему ошибка в тернарном операторе C#?

Tags: c#, тернарный-оператор

Следующая ошибка появляется при копилляции кода:

> В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента и создание нового объекта

Код:

```
int result = 0;
int right, wrong = 0;
result == textBox1.Text.ToInt() ? right++ : wrong++;
```

Почему здесь ошибка?
Хотя здесь всё отлично работает

```
if (result == textBox1.Text.ToInt())
   right++;
else
   wrong++;
```

P.S. На расширение ToInt не смотрите это мой *extension method*

Comment: Вместо `==` видимо должен быть `=`. И цитата очень странная про "дикремент"

Comment: @alexolut, а что странного в цитате про декремент?

Comment: Ошибка была в слове, просто из Украины не очень богатый русский словарный запас

Comment: а попробуйте `var v =result == textBox1.Text.ToInt() ? right++ : wrong++;` что получается?

Comment: @VladimirT, получится _выражение присваивания_ и все заработает

Comment: Всё я уже решение проблемы нашёл спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тернарный оператор - это некое подобие *функции*, т.е он возвращает одно из двух значений.

Поясняю. Есть код:

```
var result = condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

По сути это эквивалентно следующему коду:

```
var result = GetValue(condition);

int GetValue(bool condition)
{
    if (condition)
        return valueIfTrue;
    else
        return valueIfFalse;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Выражение *тернарный оператор* **НЕ** является выражением *присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента и создание нового объекта*.

Поэтому и появляется данная ошибка.

Для решения, можно заменить данное выражение на `if`.

Answer (score 2):

```
result ==
```

Вы делаете сравнение, а нужно присваивание:

```
result = textBox1.Text.ToInt() ? ++right : ++wrong;
```

Обратите еще внимание я использовал префиксный инкремент вместо постфиксного, иначе у вас получилось `result = 0`.

---

**UPD:** Если вам нужно провести какие-либо операции в зависимости от некоего условия- не надо использовать тернарный оператор, используйте простой `if`:

```
if (result == textBox1.Text.ToInt())
    right++;
else
    wrong++;
```

Тернарный оператор используется, когда надо получить одно из двух выражений в зависимости от условия:

> Условный оператор `(?:)`, известный как тернарный условный оператор,
>   возвращает одно из двух значений в зависимости от значения логического
>   выражения. [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: Я наверно что-то не понимаю. Мне нужно проверку если result равен тексту введенному тогда прибавляем к переменной right 1 а если нет то к wrong

Comment: А почему здесь тернарный оператор не сработает

Comment: Всё понял спасибо

Comment: 3 минуты помечу как ответ

Answer (score 1):

Справедливости ради, здесь можно и тернарный оператор пофиксить, но это лютейший говнокод :)

```
int result = 0;
int right = 0;
int wrong = 0;
int fixer = (result == textBox1.Text.ToInt()) ? right++ : wrong++;
```

Comment: Но зачем? Вы его пофиксили, но выделили память для еще одного int32.

Comment: @Anamnian ну я и назвал такое решение говнокодом, пример просто может улучшить понимание работы инкремента и тернарного оператора, но, очевидно, не рекомендуется к использованию.

Comment: Если сделать то что я просил, то прийдётся ещё написать строк 10 кода а мне не нужно лишнего хлама

Comment: @Anamnian Ну можно еще как-то так: `(result == textBox1.Text.ToInt() ? right++ : wrong++).ToString();`